# Javascript - Calendar does not work on Safari

Tags: javascript, date, safari, calendar

I programmed a calendar in which you can click on a date to get it shown. It works fine in all browsers except Safari. I searched the error for hours but i cant find it, my search on google says that i have to change the format of the date-string, but i am creating the date-object directly without using a date-string or initialization, so there must be another way. Do you find the error? I would be very thankful!

main.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            displayMyDate();
            calendar();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

functions.js:

```
var myDate = new Date();

function setStyle(id,style,value)
{
    id.style[style] = value;
}

function opacity(el,opacity)
{
        setStyle(el,"filter:","alpha(opacity="+opacity+")");
        setStyle(el,"-moz-opacity",opacity/100);
        setStyle(el,"-khtml-opacity",opacity/100);
        setStyle(el,"opacity",opacity/100);
}

function onCalendarClick(date) {
    myDate = new Date(date);
    var div = document.getElementById('myDate');
    if (div != null) {
        div.innerHTML = 'Datum: ' + myDate.toLocaleDateString();
    }
    onReturnToHome();
}

function displayMyDate() {
    document.write('<div id="myDate" onclick="onMyDateClick();">Datum: ' + myDate.toLocaleDateString() + '</div>');
}

function calendar(date)
{
    if (date == null) var date = new Date();
    else myDate =date;
        var day = date.getDate();
        var month = date.getMonth();
        var year = date.getYear();
        if(year<=200)
        {
                year += 1900;
        }
        months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'Jully', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
        days_in_month = new Array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);
        if(year%4 == 0 && year!=1900)
        {
                days_in_month[1]=29;
        }
        total = days_in_month[month];
        var date_today = day+' '+months[month]+' '+year;
        beg_j = date;
        beg_j.setDate(1);
        if(beg_j.getDate()==2)
        {
                beg_j=setDate(0);
        }
        beg_j = beg_j.getDay();
        document.write('<table class="cal_calendar" onload="opacity(document.getElementById(\'cal_body\'),20);"><tbody id="cal_body"><tr><th colspan="7">'+date_today+'</th></tr>');
        document.write('<tr class="cal_d_weeks"><th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th></tr><tr>');
        week = 0;
        for(i=1;i<=beg_j;i++)
        {
                document.write('<td class="cal_days_bef_aft">'+(days_in_month[month-1]-beg_j+i)+'</td>');
                week++;
        }
        for(i=1;i<=total;i++)
        {
                if(week==0)
                {
                        document.write('<tr>');
                }
                if(day==i)
                {
                        document.write('<td class="cal_today" onClick="onCalendarClick(\''+ year + '-' + (month+1) + '-' + i + '\');">'+i+'</td>');
                }
                else
                {
                        document.write('<td onClick="onCalendarClick(\''+ year + '-' + (month+1) + '-' + i + '\');">'+i+'</td>');
                }
                week++;
                if(week==7)
                {
                        document.write('</tr>');
                        week=0;
                }
        }
        for(i=1;week!=0;i++)
        {
                document.write('<td class="cal_days_bef_aft">'+i+'</td>');
                week++;
                if(week==7)
                {
                        document.write('</tr>');
                        week=0;
                }
        }
        document.write('</tbody></table>');
        opacity(document.getElementById('cal_body'),70);
        return true;
}
```

Comment: do you get any errors on safari console?

Comment: When you click on another date, then he shows invalid date

Comment: Using *document.write* to write snippets of invalid HTML is not a good idea, even if eventually it's "valid" (e.g. writing the table open tag in a different statement to writing the closing tag). Far better to construct the entire string and use one *document.write* when it's complete. The *language* attribute for script elements was deprecated with HTML 4 and removed since.

Answer (score 0):

The function `onReturnToHome()` is not defined. Is it just missing from your js file?

Comment: i had put the important parts out from a bigger project just for showing the important part :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that missing function, I also get errors for the date format. It seems that you use strings like '2017-1-1' to set the new dates. These are invalid formats and can't be parsed by new Date() directly. You have to add leading zeroes to every number lower than ten.

So '2017-01-20' for today instead of '2017-1-20'

(ps: Don't forget to work with the string '01' because the number 01 might be used as octal and give new errors.)

Full code, the HTML stay the same as in the original post.
In the JS I only changed the for loop inside fn calendar:

```
var myDate = new Date();

function setStyle(id,style,value) {
    id.style[style] = value;
}

function opacity(el,opacity) {
        setStyle(el,"filter:","alpha(opacity="+opacity+")");
        setStyle(el,"-moz-opacity",opacity/100);
        setStyle(el,"-khtml-opacity",opacity/100);
        setStyle(el,"opacity",opacity/100);
}

function onCalendarClick(date) {
    myDate = new Date(date);
    var div = document.getElementById('myDate');
    if (div != null) {
        div.innerHTML = 'Datum: ' + myDate.toLocaleDateString();
    }
    //onReturnToHome();
}

function displayMyDate() {
    document.write('<div id="myDate" onclick="onMyDateClick();">Datum: ' + myDate.toLocaleDateString() + '</div>');
}

function calendar(date) {
    if (date == null) var date = new Date();
    else myDate =date;
        var day = date.getDate();
        var month = date.getMonth();
        var year = date.getYear();
        if(year<=200)
        {
                year += 1900;
        }
        months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'Jully', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
        days_in_month = new Array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);
        if(year%4 == 0 && year!=1900)
        {
                days_in_month[1]=29;
        }
        total = days_in_month[month];
        var date_today = day+' '+months[month]+' '+year;
        beg_j = date;
        beg_j.setDate(1);
        if(beg_j.getDate()==2)
        {
                beg_j=setDate(0);
        }
        beg_j = beg_j.getDay();
        document.write('<table class="cal_calendar" onload="opacity(document.getElementById(\'cal_body\'),20);"><tbody id="cal_body"><tr><th colspan="7">'+date_today+'</th></tr>');
        document.write('<tr class="cal_d_weeks"><th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th></tr><tr>');
        week = 0;
        for(i=1;i<=beg_j;i++)
        {
                document.write('<td class="cal_days_bef_aft">'+(days_in_month[month-1]-beg_j+i)+'</td>');
                week++;
        }
        for(i=1;i<=total;i++)
        {
            var dateToWrite = (i < 10) ? '0' + i : i;
            var monthToWrite = (month + 1 < 10) ? '0' + (month + 1) : month + 1;
                if(week==0)
                {
                        document.write('<tr>');
                }
                if(day==i)
                {
                        document.write('<td class="cal_today" onClick="onCalendarClick(\''+ year + '-' + monthToWrite + '-' + dateToWrite + '\');">'+ dateToWrite +'</td>');
                }
                else
                {
                        document.write('<td onClick="onCalendarClick(\''+ year + '-' + monthToWrite + '-' + dateToWrite + '\');">'+ dateToWrite +'</td>');
                }
                week++;
                if(week==7)
                {
                        document.write('</tr>');
                        week=0;
                }
        }
        for(i=1;week!=0;i++)
        {
                document.write('<td class="cal_days_bef_aft">'+i+'</td>');
                week++;
                if(week==7)
                {
                        document.write('</tr>');
                        week=0;
                }
        }
        document.write('</tbody></table>');
        opacity(document.getElementById('cal_body'),70);
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) Can you just say me where you made the changes or can you post the edited code? hen i try to enter it, it works wrong

Comment: Added the block that I changed. The ternary can be replaced by a normal if/else if you prefer. Don't forget to also replace i in the html.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! But this also doesnt work correctly :( And I dont know what you mean what i should replace in the html file, sorry for my bad skills :D But i thank you very much for your help! Maybe we find my error!

Comment: Editted to add the full JS I used. I tested everything like this: Copy/paste that HTML into a new .html file. Copy/paste the JS into a new .js file. This specific date problem is now solved for me on IE11 and Chrome55. I get no errors and one warning: that the HTML doctype isn't html5. Maybe the problem is somewhere in a different part of the code. Do you still get Invalid date error? If so, open your console, inspect the DOM and check that your table cells containing the dates are rendered in this format: `<td onclick="onCalendarClick('2017-01-01');">01</td>`.

Comment: Using `new Date('2017-01-20')` will treat the date as UTC, which may produce unexpected results for users west of Greenwich. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Shilly, your problem stems from `new Date(date)` where *date* is an unsupported and non–standard format.

Generally, you should not parse strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse) as it's largely implementation dependent and inconsistent across implementations.

For example, if you change to an ISO 8601 format and use:

```
var date = new Date('2017-01-20')
```

then '2017-01-20' will be parsed as UTC, so for users west of Greenwich the date may appear to be one day earlier than expected unless you're using UTC for everything (and then you maybe caught out by daylight saving).

Far better to either manually parse the string or use a library.

Comment: For the record, calculating everything in UTC and then do the locale conversion if needed, is a best practice where I work, since you want to be able to compare dates around the world.

Comment: @Shilly—sure, I don't think anything I posted contradicts that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, this is the solution:

```
myDate = new Date(date.replace(/-/g, "/"));
```

instead of

```
myDate = new Date(date);
```

in function onCalendarClick(date)